can I use OR-Tools for conditional based sports team assignments?
I have 160 players signed up for a baseball league age group. I want to have exactly 16 teams of 10 players. Each team starts with an assigned Head coach and the coach's son, so that leaves 144 more players to assign. The players are have 5 optional fields they can fill out for special requests: coach, friend 1, friend 2, friend 3, their school,
None of these requests are require or guaranteed. So I want to model or-tools to create the teams as follows:for each player, their score starts at 0
If the coach request is matched, the award is 10 points.  Each of the friend requests matched, is awarded 3 points. if the school is matched by 33% of the team, the award is 2 points. If no requests are matched, the score is -1 point. Finally, if no requests are given, the score is 0 points regardless of team plaecment.
The objective for or-tools would be to maximize the total score of the 144 players, not any one player's score.
Is this approach possible using or-tools? I believe it is not since the state of the solve is not available, so knowing if the friend requests have been satisfied based on the state of the assignments is not known and thus cannot be scored. But I have been thinking about this for weeks, and wanted to ask before I gave up on the thought of using or-tools to solve this.
I believe it is not possible since the state of the solve is not available, so knowing if the friend requests have been satisfied based on the state of the assignments is not known and thus cannot be scored. But I have been thinking about this for weeks, and wanted to ask before I gave up on the thought of using or-tools to solve this.
Note this is currently done manually for each age group and the parents of the players complain often that their requests are not fulfilled. So the hope is the maximization of the score, will satisify as many requests as possible.

This is completely possible in a standard ILP (Integer Linear Program).  There are several packages that can support formulating and solving this problem, or-tools is certainly one of them, but there are many.

So the challenge now is to either give this a go and try coding it up in or-tools or pulp or pyomo or ask for help from scratch, which usually isn't a great Stack Overflow question... and truthfully, the problem construct really sounds like you are asking somebody to do your homework assignment for an LP course.  ;)

I'm a 61 year retired software engineer and I volunteer for the local baseball league in my town.

Awesome.  I'd like to help anyone who volunteers to help youth sports.  It would be easier if we took this discussion outside of SO to get some additional details.  If you follow link to my profile and then to the website listed at top of my profile, you can contact me via email through the website link.  I'd like to volunteer to help get things started.
